# Is there a way to loop through a range and return a formula in the cell next to it if there is data?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have been researching through google and stack overflow to see if I can find a similar problem, but I haven't seen it yet.

I am trying to tell excel to look at an entire range (entire column F) within my dataset (The dataset amount changes often). This column gets generated with Vendor numbers or blanks. I need to loop through the entire column and each cell and write a logical statement where If there is a vendor number in the specific cell within Column F, return a VLOOKUP in Column G in the same row that looks up the vendor number in column F. And if there is no data in column F in a particular cell, I need it to insert an equals sign and point to column Q but in the same Row. So for example, if F13 is Blank, I need to insert in cell G13 "=Q13" and so on for each cell. So if F14 is Blank, G14 would have to be "Q14". And if there is a vendor number in F20, I would need to return a VLOOKUP in G20 such as "=VLOOKUP(F20,Mapping!$A$4:$B$1000,2,FALSE)".

This is what I currently have so far, but I am really struggling on how to loop through and tell excel to point to the same row but different column within the code.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Dim CL As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("LastRow")
For Each CL In Rng
If CL.Value = "" Then
    CL.Value = "=VLOOKUP("
```

If I am not on the right track, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to have a formula in the cell or a value?

Comment: I am trying to return a VLOOKUP if there is a vendor number and if the cell is blank, I need to return "=Qx" where the x is the row it is looping through, so if F13 is blank, it would have to insert "=Q13" in Cell G13. If F14 has a vendor number, it would insert the formula "=VLOOKUP(F14,Mapping!$A$4:$B$1000,2,FALSE) in G14.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rc As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
rc = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To rc
    If ws.Range("F" & i) <> "" Or Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("F" & i).Value) Then
        ws.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F" & i & ",Mapping!$A$4:$B$1000,2,FALSE)"
    Else
        ws.Range("G" & i).Value = ws.Range("Q" & i).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: @BigBen Yeah, forgot to edit that part... Just copied from above. I added in the edits.

Comment: Also; if heimy22 wants a formula, the second part should not have the value. Something like `ws.Range("G" & i).Formula = "=" & ws.Range("Q" & i).Address(0,0)` might work.

Comment: thanks for your help! So it is inserting VLOOKUP for everythign right now, and I i need it to start in F2.  So it is not taking into account the blank cells, instead it is inserting vlookup when it should be pointing to column Q

Comment: To make it start from F2, just change the line `For i = 1 To rc` to `For i = 2 To rc`. For the "all VLOOKUP" problem: you have probably cells with "invisible" values in them, like a space (" ") or simply *nothing* (like "" or "'"). Either you get rid of them or change the if condition. If you have only *nothing* then `If ws.Range("F" & i) <> "" Then` will be enouth. Otherwise use `If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ws.Range("F" & i), " ", "") <> "" Then`.